# Stream to generate Map with Integer key and Set of values

Tags: java, dictionary, stream, set

I recently stumbled across an interesting Stream challenge, having the requirement to
**create a Java (8) Stream that reads integers from an input file and generates a Map that maps the numbers to their corresponding smallest prime factors**.

My take so far:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Files.lines(Path.of("nums.txt")).filter(s -> Integer.parseInt(s) > 2).map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> {
                        if(i == 2) return 2;
                        var divisors = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, i).filter(j -> i % j== 0).boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return divisors.stream().filter(integer -> {
                            for(int ii = 2; ii < Math.sqrt(integer); ii++) {
                                if(integer % ii == 0) return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }).findFirst().orElse(-1);
                    }, String::valueOf
                    , (s1, s2) -> s1 + ";" + s2));
```

Now without a merge BiFunction I would be getting duplicate key exceptions, so to avoid that I
did the workaround from above, it concatenates similarly mapping values with a semicolon.

I find this solution kind of lame however and would like to know, whether it is possible for my map to have a **Set**
implementation for its second type argument and collect the similarly mapping values into a set.

The main problem is that if eg. I instantiate the new HashMap in the KeyMapper function, it's always going to return for each duplicate key a new one, therefore the merging attempt of the two HashSets **was always in vain**.

*P.s. Feedback about the stream itself is also well-received, I am not sure if this approach is unnecessarily complex.*

Comment: Let's say the file contains `8 9 10 11`, the description you gave ("maps the numbers to their corresponding smallest prime factors") makes it sound like the result should be `[8=2, 9=3, 10=2, 11=11]`, it that correct? Because your code seems to want to build a result with `[2=8;10, 3=9, 11=11]`, but that doesn't fit the description you gave.

Comment: *FYI:* 1) You should flip the `filter` and `maps` calls, so you don't have to call `parseInt` twice. --- 2) The `divisors.stream()...` logic is unnecessary, because the smallest divisor is by its very nature a prime number, so you don't have to check for that.

Comment: ***Hint:*** To have a `Set` as the map value, use `groupingBy​()` instead of `toMap`, as in `Collectors.groupingBy​(keyMapper, Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Agree with @Andreas, you seem to have the mapping backwards.  It makes no sense for the input to include duplicate numbers (why produce the same answer twice?) so there should never be duplicate keys.  Your description of the problem implies this is the case.

Comment: I might have confused the mapping expression, so yes, the awaited result for your example would be something like [2=[8,10],3=[9],11=[11]]. Also, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Then the solution is the hint in my [3rd comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157639/stream-to-generate-map-with-integer-key-and-set-of-values#comment109932926_62157639).

Comment: @JimGarrison it's not about duplicate numbers (well, there is no reason there shouldn't be any duplicates either), I was reffering to duplicate values in terms of the mapping, like the case in Andreas' example with eight and ten. Again, wording mistake

Comment: @Andreas That is the solution indeed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, questions like this are subject to interpretation.  For example, what if one did something like this?

```
String file = "<number file>";
try {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> factors = new HashMap<>();
            Files.lines(Path.of(file)).map(Integer::parseInt).forEach(n-> {

                //code here to fill the map factors
            });
} catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or something like this

```
String file = "<number file>";
try {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> factors =
            Files.lines(Path.of(file)).map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i,
                            i -> primeFactors(i)));
} catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}

public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int i) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    // code here to find the factors
    return factors;
}
```

There are several advanced algorithms that exist to factor composite numbers.  These algorithms do not necessarily lend themselves to `stream` processing.